# Can i say this is a connection leak?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-leaks

Web Server Environment : Windows 2008 R2

Database Server Environment : SQL Server 2008

Background : I want to use sql profiler to trace which connection cause connection leak.

SQL server Profiler events I used:

1. Audit Login (columns : EventSubClass, EventClass, EventSequence, SPID)
2. Audit Logout (columns : EventSubClass, EventClass, EventSequence, SPID)
3. PRC:Complete (columns : TextData, EventSequence, SPID)

I found a weird logged record, I guess it is connection leak, but not very sure, the records are:

```
SPID 65,

When Audit Login, EventSubClass is 2-pooled (meaning it is pooled connection) and EventSequence is 69354

When Audit Logout, EventSubClass is 1-non pooled (meaning it is non-pooled connection) and EventSequence is 69848 (from 69354 to 69848 meaning there are some other event logs)
```

Can I say that this connection is leaking?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A pooled connection is one that is being managed between your application and the database.  It means when you close your connection, the intermediate manager takes the connection back, but keeps it open with the database.  This means that when you request a new connection, it can be provided much more quickly and efficiently than creating a new one from scratch.